# How to seperate decimal numbers written back to back

Tags: python, string, list, roman-numerals

How would it be possible to seperate a string of values (in my case, only corresponding to roman numeral values) into elements of a list?

`'10010010010100511' -> [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1,]`

I want to create something that goes like:
if it is a zero add it to side
if it's not a zero create a new element for it

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with zeros, you have to notice that every base roman numeral is either a 1 or 5 followed by some amount of zeros. You can represent that as a very simple regex.

```
import re

s = '10010010010100511'

pattern = "[1|5]0*"

matches = re.finditer(pattern=pattern, string=s)

l = [match[0] for match in matches]

print(l) # ['100', '100', '100', '10', '100', '5', '1', '1']
```

If for some reason you don't want to use regex, you can simply iterate over each character using the same principle:

```
string = '10010010010100511'

lst = []
for char in string:
    if char in ['1', '5']:
        lst.append(char)
    elif char == '0':
        lst[-1] += '0'

print(lst) # ['100', '100', '100', '10', '100', '5', '1', '1']
```

Comment: @QueensGambyte added version that does not use regex, but I don't see much of a reason to do so.

Comment: Hi i used your code and turned it into something more efficient, as I stated I'm only working with roman numerals. I used something like "if it's a zero,  lst[-1] += '0'" and "else: append". Thank your for your help

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
s='10010010010100511'
d=[]
c=0                               #introducing this new varible just to know from where 
for i in range(len(s)):           ##Here basic idea is to check next value
    if i+1 <len(s):  
        if s[i+1]!='0':           #if NEXT value is not zero thn
            d.append(s[c:i+1])    #get string from - to and add in d list
            c=len(s[:i+1])        
    else:
        d.append(s[-1])
d
```

Output:

```
['100', '100', '100', '10', '100', '5', '1', '1']
```